# C# Rich Text Box, Brace Matching

Tags: c#

Is there a good open source project with brace matching support? I was searching codeproject all day but failed to find any. Or atleast can someone advice me on how to tackle it? Thanks!

It can be in C# or VB.NET.

**Edit:** 
Sorry forgot to mention, I do not want to use other dll components since I'll have to include them in the directory to use them... I'd create my own so all I have is JUST the exe file to give out. Thanks!

Comment: FYI... I'd look into the "ILMerge" program.  It lets you combine all of your assemblies into a single file.  That might get around your "separate DLL component" issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if these provide what you need, but worth a look:

- [scintillanet](http://scintillanet.codeplex.com) is a C# wrapper around the [scintilla control](http://scintilla.org)
- ICSharpCode.TextEditor from the [SharpDevelop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/Default.aspx) project

Comment: Second the ICSharpCode.TextEditor

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention, I do not want to use other dll components since I'll have to include them in the directory to use them... I'd create my own so all I have is JUST the exe file to give out. Thanks!

Comment: both projects are open source, so you can simply use the code in your project (as long as your license is compatible, of course)